# How to make my header layout be like this?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Having a hard time to make my header look like this, where left and right take the minimum width possible :
[image]What I have so far :

[image]

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

header div {
  min-height: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `1fr 1fr 1fr` for the grid layout means that each of the items takes the same width - they share available width between them.

If you want the left and right sides to take up the minimum width necessary to contain them then set those to `auto` and the middle one to `1fr`. The middle one will then take up all the remaining width.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

header div {
  min-height: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```

**Learn more at:**

- [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#aa-grid-template-columnsgrid-template-rows)
- [An Introduction to the `fr` CSS unit](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/)

Answer (score 2):

## Use `flex-grow: 1`.

This can be easily achieved using `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1`.

Learn more about flexbox:

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

header div {
  min-height: 7rem;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

1fr 1fr 1fr create problem by giving same width
so i have used  auto 1fr auto
by set auto it can change left right width on basis relatively with parent.
or you can set values for left and right eg: 0.2fr 0.2fr

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

header div {
  min-height: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```